# Haskell lazy open and close files

Tags: file, haskell, io, lazy-evaluation

I want to read a big graph structure from hard disk in Haskell. The graph structure looks like this:

Every node has got a definition - a file describing what are the children and how are they connected (these graphs are serialized using `Data.Serialize`.

Every node can have children. So if I've got file `A.node` I can have directory `A` containing children of `A` node (in the form of `<X>.node` files and directories).

I want to be able to traverse this graph using Haskell and load to memory and unserialize only needed files. So If I for example traverse the graph in the way of `A->B->C` (where `B` is child of `A` etc), then Haskell should read files `A.node`, `A/B.node` and `A/B/C.node`. The next time I traverse the graph, the files should **NOT** be read again, because we did it already.

How can I do this the best way?

Comment: Do you want to contents of the files being read lazily or also only open the file when needed?

Comment: I want to open and close the file lazily if its possible.

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want to cache the file contents, i.e. don't read the file again when it already has been read? Because this sort if thing you're trying to do sounds like a bad idea to me. You probably want to use something like [pipes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes) or [conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit)

Comment: @bennofs - You are right - my question was not clear - I've edited it to show exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are libraries that give you a pure value that represents a full directory tree, and will only read those directories and file that are actually used. By virtue of lazy evaluation, the second time you access such a file it will already by in memory.

Check out [directory-tree](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-tree), especially the [`readDirectoryWithL`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/directory-tree/0.11.0/doc/html/System-Directory-Tree.html#v%3areadDirectoryWithL) function.

Comment: Thank you, but would it work well for my purposes? I've got a graph structure - so I want to UNSERIALIZE EACH FILE LAZILY. You've told it will read a file when I access it, but I want on the beginning to run "unserialize" on all files (lazily) to a graph structure and "read" them only when traversing the UNSERIALIZED GRAPH?

Comment: Yes, that should work. The file contents are just like any other lazy value, so in `y = unserialize x` x isn't evaluated (= the file isn't read) until y is needed.

Comment: There is a problem with `directory-tree` - **when reading the file name, the file is getting read also**. It is impossible to read filename without reading the content of the file - I think this is a logical bug in this library. The sample code: http://pastebin.com/ipbe8P3P. Additional - do you thing using somethink like `iteratee` would help with this problem somehow?

Comment: @danilo2: Did you file a bug at https://github.com/jberryman/directory-tree/issues?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner I've send a mail to the author yesterday - and filed the bug right now.